# How Mysql Query Plan is generated?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, innodb

Mysql before executing a query with multiple joins. It creates multiple query plan and find the lowest cost plan to execute the query(approx).

My questions are

1. How the optimiser will perform a cost-based calculation to select a plan on what basis(like number of fields in the where condition)?
2. How Mysql Stats works for creating multiple plan within less time?
3. Is there any formula(or steps) to generate query plan by ourself?

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197969/how-mysql-query-plan-is-generated  See answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, people use `EXPLAIN` so they can see the different ways SQL is considering the execution of a query and if they see a way to improve the DB structure to make it more efficient they can change it. At the university we have been thought about some logic how it does what it does but it is totally dependent on the implementation so MariaDB MySQL, Percona MySQL and an Oracle DB will use different methods, although mostly the same logic but there can be differences and optimizations.

I suggest you check the specific [SQL's manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) and the corresponding entries, you actually made me interested in this so I will do that too now and send an update if I find something noteworthy or interesting :)

Can I ask why do you want to generate it yourself, so maybe we can give some more specific suggestion? You can query the plan so you maybe want to try and generate a more optimized plan or some totally unique for some reason?